# angular Location.onUrlChange how to unsubscribe properly

Tags: javascript, angular

Angular's Location service has a method `onUrlChange` that registers url events that popstate or hashchange don't, and I need that for a part of my project.

```
  /**
   * Registers a URL change listener. Use to catch updates performed by the Angular
   * framework that are not detectible through "popstate" or "hashchange" events.
   *
   * @param fn The change handler function, which take a URL and a location history state.
   */
  onUrlChange(fn: (url: string, state: unknown) => void) {
    this._urlChangeListeners.push(fn);
    this.subscribe(v => { this._notifyUrlChangeListeners(v.url, v.state); });
  }
```

Other than usually, there's no subscription returned, so we can't unsubscribe on destroy. The listener is still intact after navigating away from the route that needs to listen to those events.

My ugly hack for the moment is to filter `Location`s private `_urlChangeListeners` `onDestroy`, but that relies on `String(fn) !== '(change) => this.urlFileHandler(change)'` and clearly isn't a nice way.

Is there any other possibility to remove that listener from the listeners?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really an answer to the question but I decided to subscribe to it once and use an observable. For example:

```
  import { Location } from '@angular/common';

  export class MyService {
    public urlChanged = new Subject();

    constructor(private location: Location) {
      // This is a shared service so the code only gets called once
      location.onUrlChange((url, state) => {
        this.urlChanged.next({ url, state });
      });
    }
 }
```

Then subscribe to it in the normal way, for example:

```
  private sub;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.myService.urlChanged.subscribe(e => {
      //Do stuff
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: That's how I solved it too. It remains a mystery why the angular team decided to have that method behave like this... :-)

Answer (score 2):

To properly unsubscribe the callback, the `onUrlChange` method returns a `VoidFunction` that, on execution, will unregister the callback function.

```js
const unregister = location.onUrlChange((url, state) => { ... });

// To unregister callback
unregister();
```

https://angular.io/api/common/Location#onurlchange

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
ngOnDestroy() {
 this.location.ngOnDestroy();
}
```

Ps.: Location is injected at your constructor (`private location: Location`).

Answer (score -1):

Since I only use one event suscription, I used this when I need to remove it:

```
(this.location as any)._urlChangeListeners = [];
```